# Illustrator Pen Tool does not work and switches to a pencil with circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, pen-tool

I locked a layer. Afterwards, I can't use the pen tool because the cursor switches to a pencil and a circle with a line through it.

I designed a fashion piece using illustrator and locked the layer and then 
 created another layer under that. I did this before and I cant understand what the problem is this time!

I know if I unlock the layer, it solves the problem, but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not possible** to draw on a *locked layer*. This is what the pencil with the "don't" symbol means.... you *can't* draw on *that* layer.

You may simply need to *highlight a different layer* in the **Layers Panel**. You *can* lock a layer, then draw on an (unlocked) layer above or below the locked layer. You merely need to ensure the *unlocked* layer is highlighted in the Layers Panel.